# How to write html inside php <li onClick="selectCollege(.$value["university_tuitor"])>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

```
function foo()
{
echo '<ul id="college">';
foreach ($result as $value)
//while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<li onClick="selectCollege(\''.$value["university_tuitor"].'\')>' .$value["university_tuitor"]. '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
}

echo '<li onClick="selectCollege(\''.$value["university_tuitor"].'\')">' .$value["university_tuitor"]. '</li>';
```

unable to call ocClick function please help me out guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using IDE, it will highlight syntax errors on the go...

```
function foo()
{
echo '<ul id="college">';
    foreach ($result as $value)
    {
    echo '<li onClick="selectCollege(\''.$value["university_tuitor"].'\')>' .$value["university_tuitor"]. '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
}
```

Comment: hi can you suggest me some IDE for php development.

Comment: bro i am getting error like  unterminated regular expression literal
 

selectCountry('test')>test</li><li onClick=     while clicking and checking in fire bug

Comment: To support community, If your OP is resolved then please vote up the answers and marked one as correct..

Answer (score 1):

sir there is some code formatting issues due to ide...

```
function foo()
{
echo '<ul id="college">';
    foreach ($result as $value)
    //while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo '<li onClick="selectCollege(\''.$value["university_tuitor"].'\')>' .$value["university_tuitor"]. '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: no bro code logic error is not there the thing is that it is not able to call onclick function

Answer (score 0):

Your code contained formatting errors. I fixed it up a bit. The following will work if you pass the result set as the first parameter to the function foo.

```
function foo($result){
    echo '<ul id="college">';
    foreach ($result as $value){
        echo '<li onClick="selectCollege('.$value["university_tutor"].')>'.$value["university_tutor"].'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

If "onClick" doesn't fire in your browser, then try "onclick" instead. Some browsers tend to have bugs. I also corrected the spelling mistake of the word tutor (you had tuitor).

Comment: hi mike problem is with '<li onClick="selectCollege('.$value["university_tutor"].')>' i think this function is in view function selectCollege(val) {
$("#college").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed the HTML part.

```
echo '<li onClick="selectCollege('.$value["university_tuitor"].')>' .$value["university_tuitor"]. '</li>';
```

You should use an IDE or something that highlights syntax errors.

i recommend **PHPStorm**

Comment: i started using php storm its very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Whats the error you're getting?

First: there is a trailing curly bracket in your script before the last echo.

Second: I have re-written the script and it should work so far every other part of your script is OK.

```
function foo(){
 echo '<ul id="college">';

 foreach ($result as $value){
    //while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo "<li onclick='selectCollege(".$value['university_tuitor'].")'>".$value['university_tuitor']."</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
}

echo "<li onclick='selectCollege(".$value['university_tuitor'].")'>".$value['university_tuitor']."</li>";
```

Comment: bro i am getting error like unterminated regular expression literal selectCollege('test')>test</li><li onClick= while clicking and checking in fire bug

Comment: Edited. Quotes were missing, sorry about that. Note: Use "onclick" instead of "onClick".

Comment: but i think both are same is there any difference between both of them